# Images not loading over SSL

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

I have read as many questions as i could find but still could not resolve this issue.

When i setup the **secure and non-secure** base url with **https**, then **no images are shown on the front end**. If i change non-secure to **http** then the images show but the URL show's the (!) where it should say secure with a padlock.

In  a nutshell, i am trying to load images over **https**.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what do you have if you use new incognito window? do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check if images are hard coded as http, https and http are different urls.